# Query that treats blanks as having all possible values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

Suppose I have the following tables:

| Field_1 | Field_2 | Field_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | D |
| A | C | E |
| A | C | F |
| Z | B | G |
| Z | B | H |
| Z | C | I |

| Field_1 | Field_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | C |
| Z | B |

If I pull these into the Query Design window in Access and join the two fields with common names, I can easily pull a query that shows me the records that are 'A-C' and 'Z-B' (four records total).

Here is what I want to accomplish: Suppose in the second table, in the second record, Field_2 is Null/Blank. I want to find a way to interpret this Null field as *all* possible values (taking the other joins into account). Right now, if I delete the value in that field and run the same query, I obviously only see the 'A' records. Making it an outer join in either direction predictably does not give me the result I want.

Another way to think of it, I guess, is I want it to work like more like a filter with 'and' and 'or' logic. Is this possible/easy to do in Access? Would I be better off trying to do this with an Advanced Filter in Excel?

This example is obviously simplified: in my industry, it can be way, way more complicated. An Advanced Filter would work fine for something small like this, but my "incomplete data" table (represented here by Table_2) might be tens of thousands of records, and the "complete" dataset I would need to use to expand it is hundreds of thousands of records (at least if I were to pull a query that put all of the salient data in tabular format).

I would be delighted if someone here has encountered this problem before and has a ready solution. I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your join from, presumably, something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table2.Field_1 = Table1.Field_1
AND Table2.Field_2 = Table1.Field_2
```

To something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table2.Field_1 = Table1.Field_1
AND IIF(Table2.Field_2 IS NULL,Table1.Field_2,Table2.Field_2) = Table1.Field_2
```

Forgive me if this isn't exactly right. I think you can't use `COALESCE` in Access and I believe it should be `IIF` instead. I haven't used Access in many years unfortunately.

Anyway, the principle is you need to edit the join to say "If field 2 in table 2 is null, then use field 2 from table 1 in its place". This has the effect of matching every row from Table1.

Comment: This looks promising! I'll have to try it out on a real use case once I'm back at work. Thanks so much!

Comment: It works! Thank you! This is one of those "made the impossible possible" answers.

Comment: Happy to help :)